# Connect To MYSQL Through Virtual Machine

Tags: mysql, virtual-machine

I have windows and am running ubuntu 16.4 on a virtual machine for my analysis, I have installed and created user login and password to mysql databank through VM using this instruction:

> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04

but now I don't understand how I can connect to it with my windows browser? Is it even possible to connect to mysql from my windows because technically I have installed it on another system (VM Ubuntu 16.4)?

I would appreciate if someone could guide me since I am a beginner. thanks

Comment: What kind of network interface have you choosen ? NAT or bridged ?

Comment: What do you mean by "windows browser"? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't connect to a database server like MySQL using a browser, but rather with a dedicated client program.

Some installations of MySQL also have a web program running called phpmyadmin. You can use that web program from your browser to do things to your MySQL server.  But the digital ocean tutorial you followed doesn't install that.

You need a MySQL client program running on your Windows machine to connect to the MySQL server on your VM. Ansgar Becker's [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/) is a good choice. So is [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) from the MySQL team.

And, be sure you can ssh from your Windows machine to your VM before you try all this stuff. You'll need to know the IP address of your VM when you connect to your MySQL server from your MySQL client.

Let's say your Windows machine has IP `192.0.2.101` and your VM has IP `192.0.2.121`. You need to follow the steps in [this part of your tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04#step-3-%E2%80%94-creating-a-dedicated-mysql-user-and-granting-privileges) to create a MySQL user profile that can connect from your Windows machine.  Something like this.

```
CREATE USER 'xyz0o'@'192.0.2.101' IDENTIFIED BY 'someHardToGuessPassword';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

To create that user you need to ssh into your vm and run the `mysql` command line program.

Then from your client on your Windows machine you'll connect to the MySQL server on `192.0.2.121` using whatever username / password combination you gave in the `CREATE USER` command.

Comment: thank you very much for putting it simple, now I understand that I have only created myself a user account in mysql and have to install client program to manage my database. regarding the IP, following that link, I used the localhost because my windows IP keeps changing and also because I have to get access to a pipeline, running in a docker container, to connect to my mysql database, to be honest, I am not even sure if I have understood this part properly, this whole sql-docker-container thing is too complicated to me: https://hub.docker.com/r/urgi/docker_vre_aio

Comment: Yup. MySQL in docker in a VM on your local machine, and pretty soon you're doing network engineering.